# AngularJS libraries conflicting with each other

Tags: angularjs, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to combine my scripts in order to load only one file in HTML (make it faster).

Here's a sample code, name of libraries don't matter much, you'll get the idea :

```
// gulpfile.js
mix.scripts([
        'vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js',
        'vendor/angular.js',
        'vendor/slideout.min.js',
        'vendor/dirPaginate.js',
        'vendor/cookie.js'
    ], 'public/js/libs.js');
```

And then I do this :

```
// app.js
let app = angular.module('app', ['angular-slideout', 'cookie', 'dir-paginate'], function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
export default app;
```

I only use one file to load every NG library in my project, and then I import this app in my controllers. Now this is only an example, but I already have conflicts depending on the order of mixing these scripts in.

Any advice on processing this ? I already had to ditch some libs I wanted to use because they were conflicting with others. Going on this way, this looks like a dead end.

Comment: you have provide in module.. Shouldn't it be in config?

Comment: Does that change anything ?